# Ideas for solving this nonlinear IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, initial-value-problems

I am curious how to approach solving the initial value problem: $\begin{cases} y'(t) = 5t - 3\sqrt{y} \\ y(0) = 2 \end{cases}$.

The equation isn't separable, and more generally it is not an exact equation.  Nor does it seem to be readily convertible into an exact equation.  I am interested in obtaining at least an implicit expression for $y$.  Is it possible to use a Laplace transform to solve this nonlinear IVP?  If not, what approach might one take?

Answer (score 2):

With $v(t) = \sqrt{y(t)}$, the differential equation becomes 
$$ 2 v v' = 5 t - 3 v$$
which has the implicit solution (found with help of Maple)
$$ (2 v + 5 t)^5 (v - t)^2 = c $$
To satisfy the initial condition, you need $c = 256 \sqrt{2}$.  Thus
$$ (2 \sqrt{y} + 5 t)^5 (\sqrt{y} - t)^2 = 256 \sqrt{2}$$